# Python3 Boto describe_instances probelm

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I'm using Python 3 to get a list of ec2 instance IDs from user input, and then print some info about the instances using the describe_instances() function from boto3.

When I run my script I get this error:

```
 File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 9
    InstanceIds=[
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my code so far:

```
import sys
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
instance_id_list = input("Enter an instance ID separated by commas: ")
instance_ids = instance_id_list.split(",")
print("Deleting Instance IDs:")
for instance_id in instance_ids:
    instance = client.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            InstanceIds=[
                'instance_id',
            ]
        ]
    )
```

How can I get past this error?

Comment: This is a basic misunderstanding of Python code. You can't use an assignment statement as a list item. That's why you are getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe instance ids should be set on the same level as Filters. Here's an example from the docs:

```
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'string',
            'Values': [
                'string',
            ]
        },
    ],
    InstanceIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    DryRun=True|False,
    MaxResults=123,
    NextToken='string'
)
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm trying to get an idea of how to run describe_instances() with only the InstanceIds specified. I tried indenting it like this, but with no luck: `for instance_id in instance_ids:
    instance = client.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
        InstanceIds=[
            'instance_id',
            ]
        ]
    )` Error is the same. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: I tried writing the describe_instances function like this: `for instance_id in instance_ids:
    instance = ec2.describe_instances(
        Filters=[{'InstanceIds':'instance_id'}] 
    )` And the error I get now is: `Unknown parameter in Filters[0]: "InstanceIds", must be one of: Name, Values`

Comment: I think what you wanted is `ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=["i-0123"])`